# Ignore Word Replacement on certain pages?

Tags: civicrm-home

Is there any way to ignore word replacement for a particular page or event a particular label?

The replacement we're using applies to 99% of places so we'd like to keep using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do it with an extension.

As an alternative, my guess is the following would be the simplest:

- Do the regular word replacement
- Change the word back per individual page, with jquery via an .extra.tpl: 
  https://civicrm.org/blogs/dave-greenberg/now-its-easier-add-custom-behaviors-templates